# AWS.Alexa - Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r, function, amazon-web-services, vector, character

I'm using the `aws.alexa` package to pull historical web traffic data for 84 different websites, which are stored in a character vector called `website.names`.

The function that I'm calling – `traffic_history()` – takes a string as its primary argument, and returns a data frame containing 5 columns. Knowing that the function only returns the information for 1 site at a time, I have have tried to create a loop that pulls the traffic history of each site, and stores it in data frame called `traffic`:

```
for (i in 1:length(website.names)) {
  traffic[i] <- traffic_history(paste(website.names[i], sep=""))
}
```

Regardless of what I try, I keep getting the error: “Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0.” This is the case even when I define `traffic` to have the same dimensions as what I expect it to return:

```
traffic <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 84))
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It isn't a storage issue. It throws that error when you enter a website that the package doesn’t recognize.  Ideally it would just flag the site and return a 404 error, but for now at least it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an account to test the `traffic_history` code, but generally you don't want to be appending to a data.frame. I usually will create a list of data.frames (or [data.tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)!) then bind that list together.

```
webnames <- c("amazon.com", "apple.com")
dflist <- lapply(webnames, data.frame)
data.table::rbindlist(dflist)
#        X..i..
# 1: amazon.com
# 2:  apple.com
## OR
do.call(rbind, dflist) ## slower, but native solution
#        X..i..
# 1: amazon.com
# 2:  apple.com
```

If using a for-loop, you can preallocate the list as:

```
dflist <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(webnames))
```

Comment: Looks like a neat trick, although the idea of working with a list of lists is terrifying. I don't know if the problem is that `website.names` is 1 column with 84 rows, and that the function returns 5 columns per row, but there's got to be an easy way to store that.

Comment: It's not a lot of lists -- it's one list. You save each of the data.frame objects as a list element (one website data.frame per element), then collapse the list down to a single data.frame at the end.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment the first time. It is technically a list of lists (because data.frame inherits from list), but a nested list is nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: Even when both `website.names` and 'traffic' are data frames with 5 columns and 84 rows, I still get the same error.